# Problem with jenkins pipeline script. No signature of method is applicable for argument types:(java.lang.String) values[string]

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have class Emails, that contain loginAndEmaildependency method:

```
class Emails{
 static List<String> loginEmaildependency (String login){
  Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>()
  result.put("abc", "abc@gmail.com")
  result.put("cde", "cde@gmail.com")
  ....
  ....
  if(result.get(login.toLowerCase()) != null){
   return [result.get(login.toLowerCase())]
  }
  else {return ["xxx@gmail.com"]}
 }
}
```

Also I have 2 pipeline scripts:

```
BuildEmailExt email = null
            if (env.JOB_NAME =~ /TEST-/ || env.JOB_NAME =~ /test-/) {

                def userLogin = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()

                email = new BuildEmailExt(this, Emails.loginEmailDependency(userLogin.toString()))
                    .jobParams(["gitRepoName"         : env.gitRepoName,
                                "gitBranch  "         : env.gitBranch,
                                "skipInstallationTest": env.skipInstallationTest,
                                "skipDeployNexus"     : env.skipDeployNexus,
                                "dockerImageMq"       : dockerImageMq,
                                "dockerImageWas"      : dockerImageWas,
                                "dockerImageDb"       : dockerImageDb])
            } else {
              email = new BuildEmailExt(this, Emails.repoRecipientEmails(gitRepoName))
                    .jobParams(["gitBranch"      : env.gitBranch,
                                "skipGuiTest"    : env.skipGuiTest,
                                "skipDeployNexus": env.skipDeployNexus,
                                "forceWasInstall": env.forceWasInstall,
                                "dockerImageMq"  : dockerImageMq,
                                "dockerImageWas" : dockerImageWas,
                                "dockerImageDb"  : dockerImageDb])
            }


if (env.JOB_NAME =~ /TEST-/ || env.JOB_NAME =~ /test-/) {

            def userLogin = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()

            email = new BuildEmailExt(this, Emails.loginEmailDependency(userLogin.toString()))
                .jobParams(["gitRepoName"         : env.gitRepoName,
                            "gitBranch  "         : env.gitBranch,
                            "skipInstallationTest": env.skipInstallationTest,
                            "skipDeployNexus"     : env.skipDeployNexus,
                            "dockerImageMq"       : dockerImageMq,
                            "dockerImageWas"      : dockerImageWas,
                            "dockerImageDb"       : dockerImageDb])
        } else {
            email = new BuildEmailExt(this, Emails.Teams())
                .jobParams(["gitBranch"      : env.gitBranch,
                            "skipGuiTest"    : env.skipGuiTest,
                            "skipDeployNexus": env.skipDeployNexus,
                            "forceWasInstall": env.forceWasInstall,
                            "dockerImageMq"  : dockerImageMq,
                            "dockerImageWas" : dockerImageWas,
                            "dockerImageDb"  : dockerImageDb])
        }
```

In second script I use this script and all works successfull, but in first script i get exception: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.loginAndEmailDependency() is applicable for argument types:(java.lang.String) values:[abc]

What problem it can be?

Comment: `java.lang.Class.loginAndEmailDependency()` - check if you didn't make a typo. The error says you are trying to call this method on a `java.lang.Class` class.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak what type of typo it can be? Syntax error?

Comment: You mentioned two scripts, 1 that works and 1 that doesn't but you only show one script afterwards. Is that the script that works or the one that doesn't? Can you show the other one as well so that we can see the difference in what you've attempted?Then maybe we could see where the typo is that Szymon is talking about.

Comment: @OldSchooled ok, i edit it

Comment: `loginEmailDependency` in script and `loginAndEmaildependency` in claas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't problem with code. It was problem with jenkins settings. Two scripts had different settings and in the second jenkins doesn't seen method "loginEmailDependency"